# running rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

Why when i run task :

```
my_project> rake  import:twitter
```

Task.path: lib/task/import_twitter.rake

```
namespace :import do
   task :twitter => :environment do
     puts "importing...."
   end
end
```

then tests also run?

In the console output:

```
    importing....
    Loaded suite C:/Ruby/bin/rake
    Started


    Finished in 0.001 seconds.

    0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifica
    tions
    0% passed
```

How not to run the tests, when the task is executed?

Comment: How is your Rakefile and you rask file task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You may write your task an then write new one that'll invoke two separate tasks - run tests and yours something like `task :run_all => ['db:test:clone ', 'db:test:prepare ', 'test:units', :your_task]`

Answer (score 0):

There are no tests executed (you have always the count 0).

You get the test statistic always if you load `test/unit`. Just try a file with:

```
require 'test/unit'
```

Can you check your rakefile, if you load anywhere `test/unit`? (maybe it is in one of the required files) You may check `$"` if it contains `test/unit`

Background:
test-unit starts `at_exit` (script end) some routines and looks for test-methods inside children of Test::Unit::TestCase and executes them. After this, the statistic is written. Without tests, you get the 'empty' test statistic.